# Switch between SurfaceView and other Activity with Intent

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity, surfaceview

I would switch between a SurfaceView and go in another Activity with Intent logic. So, in the SurfaceView, for do this i wrote:

`if(condition){
Intent i = new Intent(getContext(), otherActivity.class);  getContext().startActivity(i);`

So, i tried this but doesn't work and the app stops and closes.

**Logcat:**
[image]

Someone can help me and know how resolve this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Rami http://imageshack.com/a/img673/4941/RcAOde.png

Answer (score 0):

Change it to:

```
if(condition){
  Intent i = new Intent().setClass(getContext(), otherActivity.class);
  ((Activity) getContext()).startActivity(i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From your logcat i see a **NullPointerException**.

In `onCreate()` method of your class `FineGioco.java`, you have a **null** `TextView` object in which you're trying to set a text (`TextView.setText(...);` ).

Check if your `TextView != null` before using `setText()` method.